# java Mouse Event add to yAxis

Tags: java, mouse

The question is in this mouse movement
`Integer yCoords = evt.getY();`
Consider the mouse as a pendulum on y Axis it goes up and down.
I need to auto increment a value to yAxis from i.e stop point of the mouse to 100,
but when the mouse moves back to 50, the final result should increment up to 150, and when it gets back to 100 it should be 200(auto increment with 50 again)
`yCoords += yCoords;`
doesn't do that trick

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a "Robot".

Take a look at this method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove%28int,%20int%29

You should be able to pass it the coordinates desired!

Example from: [Moving the cursor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231458/moving-the-cursor-in-java)

```
try {
    // These coordinates are screen coordinates
    int xCoord = 500;
    int yCoord = 500;

    // Move the cursor
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(xCoord, yCoord);
} catch (AWTException e) {
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to catch the mouse negative values from the stop position and add them to a variable

Comment: How about getLocation in java.awt Class PointerInfo

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html#getLocation%28%29

Comment: nothing! I'll try digging docs further, thank you for the tips

Answer (score 0):

public static  int result;

```
  int y = evt.getY();
     int i = 0;
    while (i < 1) {
        result += y;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            i++;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

            for (int x = -result; x <= result; x++) {
          p.addPoint(-x , 100- (int) (50 * fSin((x / 100.0) * 2
                * Math.PI)));           
    }

            System.out.println(result);
    }
```

What I was basicly missing in my code was a Global Variable!! that would store the last position of Y in a certain period of time, which is 1 sec for my needs. And that var for last position of y would be a reference to count for the new Y position.

Voilla simple as that!