# What type of techniques should be used to display a moving cursor in circular path in java?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to code using loop but i don't know how to move the cursor up from bottom of the screen and how to use delay method in java. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Java™ Tutorials: [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: [Moving the cursor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231458/5221149)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its clear that you might be using Robot class of java to move the cursor on screen.

How if you need to move a cursor up from bottom just decrease the y coordinate of the point using a loop and it will move the cursor up.Use Thread.sleep(int milliseconds) to show a nice animation.

Comment: it works for me....thanks.

Comment: No problem,please accept the answer(click the tick) if it worked